# Why doesn't this scheme program work as expected?

Tags: scheme, r5rs

```
(define wadd (lambda (i L)
                (if (null? L) 0
                    (+ i (car L)))
                    (set! i (+ i (car L)))
                          (set! L (cdr L))))

(wadd 9 '(1 2 3))
```

This returns nothing. I expect it to do `(3 + (2 + (9 + 1))`, which should equate to `15`. Am I using `set!` the wrong way? Can I not call `set!` within an `if` condition?

Comment: I think you meant this: (3 + (2 + (1 + 9)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I infer from your code that you intended to somehow traverse the list, but there's nothing in the `wadd` procedure that iterates over the list - no recursive call, no looping instruction, nothing: just a misused conditional and a couple of `set!`s that only get executed once. I won't try to fix the procedure in the question, is beyond repair - I'd rather show you the correct way to solve the problem. You want something along these lines:

```
(define wadd
  (lambda (i L)
    (let loop ((L L)
               (acc i))
      (if (null? L)
          acc
          (loop (cdr L) (+ (car L) acc))))))
```

When executed, the previous procedure will evaluate this expression: `(wadd 9 '(1 2 3))` like this: 
`(+ 3 (+ 2 (+ 1 9)))`. Notice that, as pointed by @Maxwell, the above operation can be expressed more concisely using [foldl](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29):

```
(define wadd
  (lambda (i L)
    (foldl + i L)))
```

As a general rule, in Scheme you won't use assignments (the `set!` instruction) as frequently as you would in an imperative, C-like language - a functional-programming style is preferred, which relies heavily on recursion and operations that don't mutate state.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you fix your indentation, your problems will become more obvious.

The function `set!` returns `<#void>` (or something of similar nothingness). Your lambda `wadd` does the following things:

1. Check if `L` is null, and either evaluate to 0 or `i` + `(car L)`, and then throw away the result.
2. Modify `i` and evaluate to nothing
3. Modify `L` and return nothing

If you put multiple statements in a lambda, they are wrapped in a `begin` statement explicitly:

```
(lambda () 1 2 3) => (lambda () (begin 1 2 3))
```

In a `begin` statement of multiple expressions in a sequence, the entire `begin` evaluates to the last statement's result:

```
(begin 1 2 3) => 3
```